# sql display in matrix form but column and row values not fixed

Tags: mysql

tables i am using

product_parameter

```
       
    id productid parameterid value
    1      1         1         10
    2      2         2         11
    3      1         2         34
    4      2         4         44
    5      3         2         55
    6      3         3         43
    7      4         1         33
    8      1         3         33
    9      1         4         24
```

and so on i want to display in form

```
         parameterid 1  2    3        4. . .
productid
1                    43 34   33       24
2                 null  11 null       44 
3
4
.
.
```

and so on rows and columns are not fixed

Answer (score 0):

tables i am using

product_parameter

Sorry wanted to correct the output format i needed after query

```
id productid parameterid value
1      1         1         10
2      2         2         11
3      1         2         34
4      2         4         44
5      3         2         55
6      3         3         43
7      4         1         33
8      1         3         33
9      1         4         24
```

and so on i want to display in form

```
         parameterid 1  2    3        4. . .
productid
1                    43 34   33       24
2                 null  11 null       44 
3
4
.
.
```

and so on... rows and columns values are not fixed

Comment: You should edit your post instead of posting this as an answer. (I've already done you the favor, though.)

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to create 2D array in application code.

In SQL you have to add a join for each column.